# compile Python code to WebAssembly for non-web environments

Tags: python, rust, iot, webassembly, bacnet

I'm currently exploring if I can use a Python-based BACnet stack due to its reliability and effectiveness in conjunction with the possibility of leveraging Rust for its WebAssembly (WASM) capabilities, particularly in a non-web browser environment for IoT purposes [as mentioned in this article](https://webassembly.org/docs/non-web/) for non-web embeddings. The main goal is to utilize Rust for specific tasks that benefit from WASM's performance, while maintaining the existing Python code for the BACnet stack. I think [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/) maybe only browser based WASM for Python and where using it for BACnet may not be feasible where BACnet is dependent on UDP communications where from my research maybe blocked by browsers for security purposes.

**Approach Overview:**
Python BACnet Stack: Continue using the existing Python codebase for the BACnet stack.

**Rust for WebAssembly:** Utilize Rust for parts of the application that could benefit from WebAssembly's performance, such as data processing or interfacing with other systems.

**Integration Strategy:** Create a mechanism for Python and Rust to communicate effectively, potentially through a data exchange format like JSON or Protobuf.

**Non-Web Browser WASM Environment:** Adapt Rust components for compatibility with non-web WASM environments, understanding their specific APIs and limitations.

**Challenges and Questions:**
Python in Non-Web WASM: Running Python in a non-web WASM environment is proving to be a challenge. Pyodide is primarily designed for web browsers, and I'm looking for tools or methods to compile Python code to WebAssembly that can work in non-web environments. Does anyone have experience or insights on accomplishing this?

**Inter-language Communication:** What are the best practices for data exchange between Python and Rust in this context? Any recommendations for efficient serialization and deserialization methods that work well with Python and WebAssembly?

**Performance Considerations:** Ensuring that the Rust-compiled WebAssembly modules are optimized for performance in a non-web environment. What are some key performance metrics to consider, and how can I benchmark these in a non-web WASM setting?

Thanks for any tips... not a lot of wisdom here but curious to explore more.

Comment: What does WASM have to do with this at all? Why don't you just write a Python module in Rust? Relatedly, why do you need a data interchange format? Just write a Python module in Rust, much like you would use C. See https://github.com/PyO3/maturin

Comment: I have gone through this process as well. Browsers do not support UDP messaging. 

I ended up building an application that runs on the PC, that the browser connects to via TCP/WebSockets. TCP/WebSockets to UDP bridge. The application sends the UDP messages for BACnet and relays the messages back to the web browser as needed. It worked but wasn't ideal

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith will look into that.

Comment: @StevenSmethurst would you think BACnet has any promises in the WASM or I think the acronym `WASI`? ... outside the browser? Like this article: https://atamel.dev/posts/2023/06-20_explore_wasm_outside_browser/ which I am still wrapping my head around where from a high level standpoint could someone create a portable `WASI` or WASM pluggin for BACnet. Am still trying to wrap my head around that on what it would look like and how other IoT platforms could interact with something this..

Comment: @bbartling I am not sure. I am coming from the BACnet side of things and I know less about the WASM side of things. 

My hope is that BACnet trends towards BACnet SC that doesn't use UDP and this problem will eventually go away on its own.

Comment: @StevenSmethurst ah that makes sense so then it would work in a browser then?? This is actually a real neat YouTube video from an S4 talk about non-browser IoT edge WASM: https://youtu.be/oRuSX-FYybU?si=FSkPJteoCAcbbR-6

Comment: @bbartling Correct, BACnet SC uses Websockets (fancy TCP) so it would be well designed to work in the web browser. BACnet SC is probably (Guess). a decade away before it gains a majority of market share.